# type '{ mail: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ mail: string; name: boolean; } name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Two parent components are sharing the same child components, but have differen properties passed.

Since `ParentB` doesn't pass the `name` props, it throws the error

```
type '{ mail: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ mail: string; name: string; } name
```

See the example:

```
const ParentA=()=>{
return (
    <>
       <Child 
         mail={project.mail}
         name={name}
      />
   </>
 )
}

const ParentB=()=>{
return (
    <>
       <Child 
         mail={project.mail}
      />
   </>
 )
}

const Child: FunctionComponent<{
  mail: string;
  name: string;
}> = ({ mail, name }) => {
}
```

I tried to solve it this way   in `Child` component, but it throws another error in jsx

```
interface ChildProps {
  mail: string;
  name: boolean;
}

interface CHildWitouthNameProps {
  mail: string;
  name?: never;
}

type Props = ChildProps | CHildWitouthNameProps;

const Child = (props: Props) => {
```

Another try was

```
const Child: FunctionComponent<{
  mail: string;
  name?: boolean;
}> = ({ mail, name }) => {
}
```

But it throws another error in jsx

`name is possibly 'undefined'`

```
return (
  <div>
     {name}
  </div>
)
```

How to fix the error?
Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last approach

```
const Child: FunctionComponent<{
  mail: string;
  name?: boolean;
}> = ({ mail, name }) => {
  
}
```

seems correct, since logically the child component must have a `mail` prop, but it doesn't necessarily need to have a `name` prop. Based on this definition, the second error you describe,

```
name is possibly 'undefined'
```

seems like TypeScript functioning as intended. It's telling you that there is a prop which might not be defined, being used in a way that would break the application if it actually was undefined. The way to fix this is by ensuring that wherever you use the `name` prop in a way that's sensitive to whether or not it's defined, you should include good checks. There are a couple ways to do this:

```
return (
  <div>
     {name || "No name given"}
  </div>
)
```

^this way fills in the name with the placeholder whenever it's not present,

```
return (
  {name && <div>
     {name}
  </div>}
)
```

^this way only renders the whole div if `name` is defined to begin with.

Again, it seems like it depends on what you're going for, but this might be some good things to try first.

Answer (score 0):

Just add ? which means that that is an optional key.

```
const ParentA=()=>{
return (
    <>
       <Child 
         mail={project.mail}
         loading={loading}
      />
   </>
 )
}

const ParentB=()=>{
return (
    <>
       <Child 
         mail={project.mail}
      />
   </>
 )
}

const Child: FunctionComponent<{
  mail: string;
  loading?: boolean;
}> = ({ mail, loadedData }) => {
}
```